# How to properly model ANN to find relationship between real value input-output data?

Tags: neural-network

I'm trying to make an ANN which could tell me if there is causality between my input and output data. Data is following: 
My input are measured values of pesticides (19 total) in an area eg:

```
 -1.031413662  -0.156086316    -1.079232918    -0.659174849    -0.734577317    -0.944137546    -0.596917991    -0.282641072    -0.023508282    3.405638835 -1.008434997    -0.102330305    -0.65961995 -0.687140701    -0.167400684    -0.4387984  -0.855708613    -0.775964435    1.283238514
```

And the output is the measured value of plant-somthing in the same area (55 total) eg:

```
0.00   0.00    0.00    13.56   0   13.56   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   13.56   0   0   0   1.69    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1.69    0   0   0   0   13.56   0   0   0   0   13.56   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Values for input are in range from -2.5 to 10, and for output from 0 to 100.
So the question I'm trying to answer is: in what measure does pesticide A affect plant-somthings.

What are good ways to model (represent) input/output neurons to be able to process the mentioned input/output data? And how to scale/convert input/output data to be useful for NN?

Is there a book/paper that I should look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a neural network cannot find the causality between output and input, but only the **correlation** (just like every other probabilistic methods). Causality can only be derived logically from reasoning (and even then, it's not always clear, it all depends on your axioms).

Secondly, about how to design a neural network to model your data, here is a pretty simple rule that can be generally applied to make a first working draft:

- set the number of input neurons = the number of input variables for one sample
- set the number of output neurons = the number of output variables for one sample
- then play with the number of hidden layers and the number of hidden neurons per hidden layer. In practice, you want to use the fewest number of hidden layers/neurons to model your data correctly, but enough so that the function approximated by your neural network fits correctly the data (else the error in output will be huge compared to the real output dataset).

Why do you need to use just enough neurons but not too much? This is because if you use a lot of hidden neurons, you are sure to overfit your data, and thus you will make a perfect prediction on your training dataset, but not in the general case when you will use real datasets. Theoretically, this is because a neural network is a function approximator, thus it can approximate any function, but using a too high order function will lead to overfitting. See PAC learning for more info on this.

So, in your precise case, the first thing to do is to clarify how many variables you have in input and in output for each sample. If it's 19 in input, then create 19 input nodes, and if you have 55 output variables, then create 55 output neurons.

About scaling and pre-processing, yes you should normalize your data between the range 0 and 1 (or -1 and 1 it's up to you and it depends on the activation function). A very good place to start is to watch the videos at the [machine learning course by Andrew Ng at Coursera](https://coursera.org/learn/machine-learning), this should get you kickstarted quickly and **correctly** (you'll be taught the tools to check that your neural network is working correctly, and this is immensely important and useful).

Note: you should check your output variables, from the sample you gave it seems they use discrete values: if the values are discrete, then you can use discrete output variables which will be a lot more precise and predictive than using real, floating values (eg, instead of having [0, 1.69, 13.56] as the possible output values, you'll have [0,1,2], this is called "binning" or multi-class categorization). In practice, this means you have to change the way your network works, by using a classification neural network (using activation functions such as sigmoid) instead of a regressive neural network (using activation functions such as logistic regression or rectified linear unit).